# De - Import a default imported package (java.lang) in java

Tags: java, package

I just have a small question, when I was working with java, there was no need to import java.lang package because it is imported by default. What if I don't want to import it to my program? No specific reason, just to know if there is something in java that helps to remove (De - Import) a default imported package.

Comment: There is no way to de-import something, but there's also no drawback to it being imported by default. Note that if you have a local class (or imported one from another package) with the same simple name, that one will be used instead of the default-imported one.

Comment: be aware that `import`ing a package is just to allow using non-qualified names for classes in that package (e.g. instead of having to write `java.lang.Object`, you can just write `Object` in your code) It does not affect the compiled code  || it is only importing the *namespace*, nothing more

Comment: Thanks for the responses but I actually don't want to remove it due to some problem I am facing, I just wanted to know whether there is something like that de - importing. Thanks again.

Comment: I understand that. But the fact that importing basically has no drawbacks (as it doesn't do anything other than allow you to use the short name) is part of the explanation *why* there's no de-import.

Comment: @JoachimSauer This is not the case here, but importing unused packages makes the code harder to read and if you happen to import 2 classes with the same name, you'd always have to fully qualify them, adding more clutter.

Comment: Thank you, now i understood why there is no "deimporting" in java